# how do I programmatically invoke labels in vis.js?

Tags: label, axis-labels, vis.js

From the docs, I am unable to determine how in vis.js (Graph3d, in particular) I can cause labels to appear on my graphs dynamically.

I would like to modify the appearance of data for different sets of x, y and z; yet, it seems that vis.js favors the configuration of a graph's appearance prior to rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtain the **Graph3d** object (maybe `graph`) and manipulate like so:

```
    var dataForLabeling = graph.dataPoints
    var someArbitraryPoint = dataForLabeling[2]
    graph._showTooltip(someArbitraryPoint)
```

(Turns out the [code for Graph3d](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/lib/graph3d/Graph3d.js) is easy to read, like docs.)